# Why are the leaves of my areca palm (indoor) turning yellow? HELP!

Tags: houseplants, leaves, plant-recommendations, palm, urban-gardening

Dear all since last week I noticed that entire leaves of my areca palm are turning yellow? In addition to the previous problem I have been having of the yellow and brown tips. I have the plant next to a window, try to moisturise the leaves everyday or every other day as it is not very humid, I water every 10 days or so when the soil gets dry.

I got the plant 6 months ago, and this is the first time this has happened.

I attach a pic showing the yellow leaves[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yellowing leaves like this usually indicate water shortage - my own palm lives on an unheated landing, and it needs watering every week with about 1-2 litres of water, depending if its summer or winter, so if yours  is in average room temperatures, 10 days seems too long. Water when the surface of the potting soil feels just about dry to the touch, water well, allow the excess to drain away from the bottom,  and empty any outer tray or pot 30 minutes after watering. You can cut off the yellowed leaf and its stem - cut it at the point of origin, or as close to as you can without damaging the rest of the stems.

Answer (score 0):

Palm fronds do die. Is it the oldest frond on that stem? Its time could just be up. The rest of the palm looks pretty healthy to me. If center fronds look good you may not have a problem. It is not realistic to expect greenhouse lushness in our homes.

Palms react slowly, so if there is a problem it did not necessarily happen yesterday. And you will not fix it tomorrow.